# Summarizing data from last 12 months in dataframe by category using python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, group-by

I am trying to create a summary of data by category for the last 12 months (excluding the current month).  I have summarized the previous 3 months with the following code, but doing so for 12 months seems cumbersome.  I am wondering if there is a more efficient and effective way of dynamically slicing data for the last 12 months.  df1 is the complete data set which I load from a DB connection using a SQL query.  I use .drop() to slice out the unwanted columns of data and only leave me with the count.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df1.Start_Date = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1.Start_Date)

today = datetime.date.today()
currentfirst = today.replace(day=1)
thirdMonth = currentfirst - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(3)
secondMonth = currentfirst - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(2)
firstMonth = currentfirst - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)

fst_label = firstMonth.strftime('%B')
snd_label = secondMonth.strftime('%B')
thd_label = thirdMonth.strftime('%B')

def monthly_vol(df, label, start_date, end_date):
    """Slices df1 into previous months and sums the volume of each change class."""
    if start_date is not None:
        df = df1[df1.Start_Date >= start_date]
    if end_date is not None:
        df = df[df.Start_Date < end_date]
    df_count = df.groupby('Change Class').count().drop(['Start_Date', 'Risk Level', 'Change Coordinator', 'Change Coordinator Group'], axis=1)
    return df_count

fst_month = monthly_vol(df1, fst_label, firstMonth, currentfirst)
snd_month = monthly_vol(df1, snd_label, secondMonth, firstMonth)
thd_month = monthly_vol(df1, thd_label, thirdMonth, secondMonth)

def month_merge(df1, df2, df3):
    """Merges monthly dataframes together."""
    new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True).merge(df3, left_index=True, right_index=True)
    new_df.columns = [fst_label, snd_label, thd_label]
    print(new_df)
    return new_df

monthly_vol = month_merge(fst_month, snd_month, thd_month)
```

This will give the output:

```
              May  April  March
Change Class                   
Emergency      36     36     32
Expedited      17     24     35
Normal        182    146    134
Standard      256    210    267
```

Bonus question:
It would be nice to get the average of the total volume for each category in the same dataframe.  Somewhat like this:

```
              May  MayAVG  April  AprilAVG   March  MarchAVG
Change Class                   
Emergency      36   7.33   36     8.65       32     6.84
Expedited      17   3.46   24     5.77       35     7.48
Normal        182   37.07  146    35.10      134    28.63
Standard      256   52.14  10     50.48      267    57.05
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is your question? Also provide a [MCVE] rather than the whole program. You can provide the input data, expected output and the minimal code that gives you your current output.

Comment: `datetime` have attributes which allow you to easily calculate the month. I.e. `df.date_col.dt.month` will give you the month. You can groupby this and easily calculate things like averages, totals, size. etc.

Comment: My question is 'What is the best way to compile a similar output as above rather than creating a `firstMonth = currentfirst - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)` variable for each month and passing it through the function.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using Dictionary ? A dictionary is a key value pair of data.
For example : {"3": "March", "4": "April" }.
So where ever you are maintaining a pair, you can instead use dictionary. 
Populate those dictionaries inside a loop.
See below.

```
month_dict = {"3": "March", "2": "April", "1": "May"} 

thirdMonth = currentfirst - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(3)
secondMonth = currentfirst - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(2)
firstMonth = currentfirst - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)


label_dict = {}

fst_label = firstMonth.strftime('%B')
snd_label = secondMonth.strftime('%B')
thd_label = thirdMonth.strftime('%B')

vol_month = {}

fst_month = monthly_vol(df1, fst_label, firstMonth, currentfirst)
snd_month = monthly_vol(df1, snd_label, secondMonth, firstMonth)
thd_month = monthly_vol(df1, thd_label, thirdMonth, secondMonth)
```

Comment: The firstMonth variable changes every month I run the script i.e. the first Month right now is May, but next month it would be June.

Comment: It doesn't change the logic. 
You populate dictionary of months every time you run the script ie every month. The dictionary of months is not hard coded. I gave just and example to show how it will look like.

Comment: How does the dictionary interact with `pd.offsets.MonthBegin()`?  Those are generating a datetime that is either 1, 2, or 3 months prior to the currentfirst variable.